# Addressing questions caused by a common tutorial, but dealing with different aspects

Tags: discussion, questions

In the last year or so, I've been seeing lots of questions that are related to many different aspects, but have a common factor: a certain YouTube tutorial<sup>[see below note]</sup>.

Problem is, that tutorial suggests a terrible amount of bad practices, but since it has become quite popular and appears frequently in top results, I can see a lot of posts caused by its issues.
The average is about 4-5 a week (topping at more than 3 a day), I know it's not a huge amount, but after all this time, it got *really* annoying. I only follow a few tags and I love to spend time in answering that very small niche, but I also like to spend some quality time in doing that while knowing that I'm still useful to the community, instead putting hours of my time trying to "save" people from irresponsible wannabe-teachers that only care about views (and the income they get from those).

I know I could just downvote and ignore most of those questions, but I don't believe that would be a proper approach for the spirit of SO, and, honestly, I feel sorry for those beginners who are daily "instructed" with such amount of .

I cannot even count the amount of issues.
Starting from generic ones (superficial usage of global variables, generic exceptions, bad/inconsistent code styling and syntax), going through security related (full string SQL queries) or usage inconsistency (properties arbitrarily set from the UI designer or by code without distinction), and ending with those specifically related to the tutorial subject (UI that completely ignores basic aspects as layout management or display issues, wrong usage of specifically intended classes). Not to mention typos shown in the video: they have been corrected in the linked repo, but we all know what that could mean.

I am completely aware that almost all the aspects above *can* be part of a tutorial (show a *wrong* way to do things for the *right* reasons), but a *responsible* tutorial should also warn whether an explained approach is only intended for explanation purposes. I have been a teacher and aware about didactic aspects since I was a teenager: if you want to teach something, you *must* be aware about the importance, meaning, results and implications of what you're teaching.

Needless to say, that **never** happens in those tutorials. They just don't realize (nor care about) any of that.

Now, after all this time, I got really annoyed, and I really feel sorry for those poor beginners.
I obviously tried to contact the author (which, not unexpectedly, ignored me) and commented the videos (the first comments got obviously deleted, their careful attention to their users obviously diminished after that...), but that's not the point.

Until now, I decided to write a specific comment to each question (addressing the above) or eventually answer them for specific aspects, but I don't think I could take this any more.

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75512330/2001654) gathered my attention, and it seems that it could fit a *generic* answer related to the whole problem: my intention was to use it as a target for future duplicates that are clearly caused by that tutorial. I would answer the specific problem (a bit *broadly*, possibly) and eventually add further notes related to other issues caused by that tutorial. I was not going to address **all** issues, but, at least, the most important ones.

Yet, I am not really sure about it. I know that SO posts should be specific to a problem that is being asked, not generally aimed.

Still, the conflict remains:

- decide to ignore those posts at all (and I'd feel really sorry for those beginners);
- constantly "lose" time by writing answers caused by an irresponsible youtuber, time which could be better used to focus on more important questions;
- keep writing comments about that (and still not really answering the questions);
- create the above mentioned "template" answer, which would seemly be against SO rules;

<sup>*NOTE*: Sorry, but I won't provide the direct link to that tutorial: it already has too many views and references, so I don't want to contribute to its visibility in any direct way. If you want to see it, its first video has an YouTube ID that starts with `RxGlB9` and is followed by `U64fg`.</sup>

Comment: I call that the tutorial effect. The person who created that pretty shiny looking video was probably a novice themselves and in their excitement just HAD to share their epic knowledge with the world. Novices teaching other novices... it takes a while longer for code to really start to become mature under those conditions. But ask yourself this: if that video wouldn't exist, would these people who obviously do not cross-reference their findings really ask better questions? The internet is full of misinformation and half-truths, they'll probably just find the next video that looks shiny.

Comment: @Gimby That is a good point; there will always be some bad tutorial around (and people that cannot understand their validity), but I'm not ranting about the existence of *any* bad tutorial, I'm aware of them and I learned to live with that, but statistically, a tutorial can be wrong about one or few aspects: when that happens, we usually have some *specific* answers (or duplicates) that can solve those issues. Unfortunately, that video does exist, it's wrong about a plethora of aspects, its visibility is increased by its very popularity - and we know that popularity doesn't mean quality.

Comment: @Gimby When people post a question about an issue caused by that video, and that has a single, main issue, I can answer or find a duplicate and eventually add further notes about the other "minor" (which are not really *minor*) problems. Sadly, reality is that most of the times the posts that are *caused* by that video do not have just that "single, main issue", but *a lot*, and they are generally all the same (almost all of them have the problems listed above): they may be asking about one problem, but answering that single problem often results in having to explain and fix all the others.

Comment: If only a SME could create a competing tutorial that isn't full of misinformation/poor practices. They're probably instead focusing on using a tutorial format that ages better. videos age about as well as printed books tutorials.

Comment: It is time to make a reaction video on YouTube with a [click bait title](https://odysee.com/@eevblog:7/eevblab-99-spam-bot-youtube-space:6) like *"The terrifying new discovery in Hola's Python tutorial that scares computer scientists and shocks the entire industry!"*

Comment: Or for the [more conspiratorial minded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvA6u0IXnWw): *'"I Tried To Warn You" - software engineer's LAST WARNING. It is not what we're being told. 15 dirty secrets in Hola's Python tutorial that they don't want you to know."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Gosh, that could actually be a *good* idea, as I've seen similar things in different contexts; eg. the "TwoSet Violin" channel, made by classically trained professional musicians, well aware about how social networks work (not only *socially* speaking, but also considering software algorithms), and who use that knowledge to provide quality/educational content instead, while still being entertaining (thus, popular). And, being I a classically trained (and professionally active) musician myself, I *do* realize the potential in such content usage. Should I finally buy a webcam?

Comment: @PeterMortensen perhaps you jest but you are probably not far off. If you want to combat a bad video, you need to make a reaction video to it.

Comment: "constantly "lose" time by writing answers caused by an irresponsible youtuber, time which could be better used to focus on more important questions;" - Why does each new question need a different answer? There is a fixed set of **problems** that the OPs end up with, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they're not *always* the same, sometimes the question/code doesn't involve each one of that "set" (probably because they already found a related answer), but there is also a smallest set of major problems that are common and at this point I already recognize where they come from at a glance. Still, one of the rules of SO states that you should technically only address one question per post. Maybe, I could create a question on my own, finding a good way to address the "whole set"; something like "I am doing x and y for z, but after searching it seems it's not correct, why?".

Comment: "Maybe, I could create a question on my own, finding a good way to address the "whole set" **Other than** all being things that this tutorial gets wrong, is there anything that actually *relates* these problems to each other?